# For production, should I avoid using default port of web server, DB, etc?

Tags: security, web-applications, port, port-scanning

There're many default ports well-known as specific applications, such as 3306 for MySQL,
80(or 8080) for HTTP request, etc.

When building web application for production, should I use port forwarding to avoid using
these default ports directly?

From the security standpoint I assume it's gonna be better to avoid default ports,
but I'm not security guy and not sure it's worth doing.
If it doesn't help security at all, I'd like to use default ports just because
of one less thing to configure.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your attacker model, ie. who you think would attack your application, who you want to defend it against.

An attacker that specifically targets your website will fairly easily find your services regardless of the port they use. So against a skilled, targeted attacker, this has close to zero benefit. Your services should be secure against an attacker that knows the port where they listen (you should assume they know it when designing security controls).

However, most "attacks" (if we can call them that) that you will encounter are just port scans, looking for interesting servers. This will have two important consequences.

1. If you use default ports, you will have a lot of noise in your logs. This might lead to DoS (root partition full) if misconfigured enough, or just to a difficulty finding relevant info in your logs when needed.
2. Anytime in the future your server might be vulnerable enough so that such an automated attack might find and compromise it. Consider for example a vulnerability that you should have patched, but have not yet done so. Most automated scans will go for the default port and not bother with full scans (but some might).

So it's not so black and white, but for the reasons above, it might still make sense to use non-default ports (or not, it's your decision based on your risk appetite and threat model).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough guideline! It totally makes sense and actually I decided to use non-default ports with the consideration of my app's case.